# How to load tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tokenize

I am trying to follow the Tensorflow text classification example [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification). I want to save the tokenized dataset by using tf.data.experimental.save(). However, I can't load it properly. What should I do to load it properly? The offical Colab link is [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/text_classification.ipynb).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split the batch labelled dataset as 2 pieces

1. Training Dataset
2. Training Dataset Label

and fit with model.fit(x=training_dataset, y=training_dataset_label)